# How to zoom background together with graph using JUNG?

Tags: java, jung

It's easy to zoom in/out graph using GraphZoomScrollPane in JUNG. However, I cannot make the graph background image zooming together with the graph itself. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If I can understand you correctly, try to see JUNG's `StaticLayout` example in **WorldMapGraphDemo.class** sample from JUNG example source package. In this example, you can zoom in/out both layout and view--in effect the background image will zoom in/out together with the elements of the graph.

Comment: Thanks for your comment :), i'm following your suggested example and it's work! Just one more question, the zooming effect is not quite as i expected, when i zoom out to background image's actual size, i can only zoom out the graph, is there any solution for this?

Comment: The default zoom setting is to do layout scaling for zooming in and view scaling for zooming out.  (I think this is the CrossoverScaling plugin.)  This is configurable; you just need to swap out the plugin.